# nmcli not showing connection

Tags: server, vpn, ipsec, nmcli, l2tp

I imported L2TP/IPsec VPN connection configuration file from Ubuntu mate 20.04 /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/ to Ubuntu server 20.04
Next, on the Ubuntu server 20.04 PC, I check the nmcli connection "sudo nmcli con" in response I get an "empty field"
How to solve this problem? [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JuPyC.jpg)

Comment: did you restart network manager?

Comment: Please show the status of devices known to NetworkManager: $ nmcli d

Comment: Hello. Problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem solved.
I switched to Network-Manager in Netplan.

Since 17.10 Ubuntu Server, the Netplan utility has been used to manage the network configuration.

So, create this file:

```
/etc/netplan/00-enable-network-manager.yaml
```

And put this content and save:

```
network:
  version: 2
  renderer: NetworkManager
```

Then disable the default configuration:

```
cd /etc/netplan
sudo mv 00-installer-config.yaml 00-installer-config.yaml.bak
```

It may need a restart of the NetworkManager service or maybe a reboot.

IMPORTANT: before doing so, be sure that you have physical access to the server, since it may be not reachable after this change.